# Android browser does not update DOM while keyboard open

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard-events, android-browser

I have a `textarea` element on a web page, with some JavaScript code which executes on certain keyboard events; among other things the JS code should make some visible updates to the page.

On desktop browsers, and also on iOS this works fine, however on the stock Android browser (Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.0.4) none of the page updates occur until the onscreen keyboard is closed. The page updates seem to get 'buffered' and once the keyboard closes they all run in quick succession.

I know the event handlers are running while the keyboard is open, because if I insert some `alert` statements into them then the alert dialogs appear with each keypress rather than waiting for the keyboard to close.

Does anyone else seen this, or know of a workaround?

Comment: Make sure you're not doing something like: myInputField.onclick = function(e){setTimeout(doFocus(e), 100)}... the delayed call might get discarded.

Comment: @Amalgovinus nope, there are no timeouts/intervals involved, good thought though